# Url not found on ajax reqest Django

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

I want to trigger on update view via ajax call but showing the URL is not found. Any help would be appreciated

**ajax:**

```
$(document).on("change", "#id_device_type", function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/register-non-device/view/',
            type: "GET",
            dataType:  'json',
            data: $(this).val()
        });
    });
```

**url:**

```
path('register-non-device/view/<int:pk>/', RegisterNonDeviceView.as_view(), name='register-non-device')
```

**View:**

```
class RegisterNonDeviceView(UpdateView):
    model = AnticipatedNonDevice
    form_class = AnticipatedNonDeviceForm
    template_name = 'anticipated_non_device.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('app:po-search-non-device')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the URL definition the primary key should be the part of the URL, not a query parameter:

```
$(document).on("change", "#id_device_type", function() {
    var id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: `/register-non-device/view/${id}/`,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType:  'json'
    });
});
```

Comment: Still I'm getting this error: `django.template.base.VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [helper] in <AnticipatedNonDeviceForm bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(po_number;delivery_date;vendor;manufacturer;model_description;device_type;order_number;cost;finale_product_id;finale_description;created_by;updated_by;is_deleted;manufacturerid;vendorid;devicetypeid;asset_number;finaleproduct_id)>
"GET /register-non-device/view/95/ HTTP/1.1" 500 210998`

Comment: That is a different issue, you try to use a non-existing key (`helper`) in the form/template. Check the `AnticipatedNonDevice` model's definition and the form in the template.